# Simple Javascript login form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, authentication

```
<form id="loginForm"> 
    <p id="usernameLabel">Username:</p>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="username"/><br>
    <p id="passwordLabel">Password: </p>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="password"/><br>
    <input id="loginButton" type="submit" value="Login!" onsubmit="validateForm()">
</form>
<p id="loginMessage">Please Login!</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        var un = document.loginForm.username.value;
        var pw = document.loginForm.password.value;
        var username = "MitchWardle"; 
        var password = "123abc456";
        if ((un == username) && (pw == password)) {
            window.location = "content.html";
            return false;
        }
        else {
            alert ("Login was unsuccessful, please check your username and password");
        }
    }
</script>
```

I have created a little login form on Javascript and I want it to navigate to Content.html when username and password are correct but when I click my Login button it just removes the text from the text box's, can anybody see whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

1. Remove onsubmit from button add it to form.
2. Change `id` of form to `name`.
3. In the `onsubmit` of form **append** `return false;`.
4. Remove `return false;` from the if statements.
5. Change `document.loginForm` line to this:

   ```
   document.forms['loginForm'].elements['username'].value //username/password depends.
   ```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

you need to return false to prevent default action of submitting the form , page gets refresh andyou loss your data, you can set type of submit button to

```
  type="button"
```

or can change onsubmit to

```
onclick="validateForm(); return false; "
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple things are off, but it's almost there:

- The `onsubmit` handler is used at the form level. Either move the `onsubmit` to the `<form>` element or change it to an `onclick` event for the `<input>` element.
- In order to reference the text fields the way you are, the `<form>` element also needs a `name` attribute. i.e. `name="loginForm"`

Comment: Moving the `onsubmit` to the `<form>` element will still allow the enter key to submit the login. @Charly's answer reminded me of this.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem as you before, and I solved it by changing the submit button to `<input type="button" onclick="login();" />`, and everything worked. However, the user then cannot submit the form with enter key (because there's no submit button in the form).